# How to delete duplicates in an google drive request

Tags: google-drive-api, duplicates, user-permissions

Hey can someone help me to just get the unique names in my drive folder.

Here is my codesnippet. I ask for a Permissionlist and extract the name. There should only be unique names in the output.

```
    public static List<Permission> retrievePermissions(Drive service,
          String fileId) {
    try {             
    PermissionList permissions = 
         service.permissions().list(fileId).execute();
          List<Permission> pem = permissions.getItems();
          for(int i = 0; i< pem.size(); i++){
              Permission Singlepem = pem.get(i);
              System.out.printf("%s \n", Singlepem.getName());
          }
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This set will maintain the order & remove the duplicates.

```
Set<Permission> s = new LinkedHashSet<>(pem);
```

here is how to iterate over the Set

```
Iterator<String> itr = s.iterator();
while(itr.hasNext()){
    Permission p = itr.next();
}
```

Comment: It seems to be quite good, but there is no s.next() function for the Set<Permission>. Any ideas ?

Comment: Yes. Instead of s.next(), do it.next(). I updated my answer. 